# Building for Android Xamarin ARM in Azure Devops

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-devops

I've created a quick build definition for a project of mine on Azure DevOps, it's a Xamarin solution.  Anyway, I was assuming that once built, I could then get the APK and install it on my phone.  But it's not installing, and without knowing what's actually wrong, I'm lead to believe that it may be the build configuration as I can do it fine from my local PC.

I've taken a screenshot of the configuration Xamarin options and the only choice of architecture is x86 or x64... surely I need ARM like I would on my local PC?  I see nowhere to select ARM though, how do I do this?  Or is this not the issue?

Nick.

[image: Build Definition]

Comment: When in doubt, `adb logcat` when installing your `apk`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause, I needed to sign the APK, for some reason I kind of expected "unknown sources" to include "Unsigned", but even though I'm using a test cert, it's now installing as expected.